# Can I use an ORM class as association table for a many-to-many realtionship in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to collect statistical information for songs (rating, play-count, last time played) from a couple of players over different devices and from different users. I use Python and [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

I came up with the following table layout:

[image: My ERP Diagram]

I can access all related `Stats` objects from my `Commit` ORM class as a list. I also want to have access to the related `Song` objects from the `Commit` class. Following the examples in the [SQLALchemy Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) I came up with an association table for the *mtm* relationship.

In code it looks like this ([full source](https://gist.github.com/brutus/7483771)):

```py
songcommits_table = Table(
  'songcommits', Base.metadata,
  Column('commit_id', Integer, ForeignKey('commits.commit_id')),
  Column('song_id', Integer, ForeignKey('songs.song_id'))
)


class Commit(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'commits'

  commit_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

  # ...

  songs = relationship(
    "Song", secondary=songcommits_table, backref="commits"
  )

  stats = relationship('Stat', backref='commit')

  def __repr__(self):
    return "<Commit {0.commit_id}>".format(self)
```

It works. But I have the feeling it might work without the table, using the info already stored in the stats table, but I have no idea how to formulate this in the ORM.

So how can I use the information (`commit_id` and `song_id`) already present on the `Stats` ORM class instead of the helper table?

Comment: did you look at the next section in the docs, [association object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#association-object)?  that's basically what you'd go for here.

Comment: Yes I did. Probably I just didn't get it. Will take another look. The docs are good and thorough, but and up to date book or something like that would help a ton.